# UICollectionViewCell not recognized?

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell

Im following a tutorial that connects to the web to fetch data and puts it into core data.  Ive set up my `UICollectionView` with a cell with its identifier but when i run the project i get this in the console:

> 2013-06-23 20:26:17.051 UICollectionView[912:c07] Unknown class MyCell
>   in Interface Builder file. 2013-06-23 20:26:17.055
>   UICollectionView[912:c07] CoreData: error: Serious application error. 
>   An exception was caught from the delegate of
>   NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key cellLabel. with userInfo {
>       NSTargetObjectUserInfoKey = ">";
>       NSUnknownUserInfoKey = cellLabel; }

ANd nothing but a blank (black) `UICollectionView`.  I did subclass `UICollectionViewCell` and called it `MyCell` and I did declare and connect a image view `IBOutlet` as well as a `UILabel` outlet called `cellLabel`.

I eliminated the `cellLabel` outlet and just left my `UIImageview` but then I get the error with `UIImageview`.

I just found an interesting bit, I compared the tutorial code with mine but its identical.  Then I compared the `MasterViewController` outlets, connections and identities and found this difference.  Their custom cell called `AFCollectionViewCell` is:

[image: Tutorial's CollectionViewCell]

but my custom cell "MyCell" is what it should be:

[image: MyCell]

Why on earth would theirs be a `UITabBarController`? That doesn't even make sense.  But then in the Identity Inspector they are both what they should be, subclasses of the respective custom cell classes.  Could this be a bug?

Comment: See if `cellLabel` is properly connected in the Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fixed...something happened when i created the project in xcode5.  It wasnt assigning target membership to the .m file.  I clicked on the target membership to check the box, even code coloring is working again and now it compiles fine.